# DataGridView prevent CellContentClick be called repeteadly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a slight issue when I want to remove one row in a DataGridView.

The first column in the Grid is a DataGridViewButtonColumn, which once clicked in any of the button from a row, remove such row.

All work fine except that once the row is removed for the dataSource, in my case is a BindingList, the event is triggered again due to another row take the place of the rowIndex which has just been removed.

The code is very simple:

```
private void dg_list_EliminarBlogClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
                e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
                e.ColumnIndex == dg_lista_blogs.Columns["Eliminar"].Index)
            {
                MessageBoxHelper.PrepToCenterMessageBoxOnForm(this);
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                     mylist.RemoveAt(dg_lista_blogs.CurrentRow.Index);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way for preventing this?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on the first line of `dg_list_EliminarBlogClick` and check the sender object for more information to help you debug the issue. It seems very weird to me that it is getting repeatedly called unless it being triggered somewhere else in the code (perhaps on page load or postback or you have a javascript function triggering it?). If you find any more information be sure to update your original post.

Comment: @MattStannett As you can see in the code, the if statement is always true, that means that sender is a DataVGridViewButtonColumn, e.indexRow & e.ColumnIndex are always the same.

Comment: What happens if there are only two rows and you delete the first one? The second one will move into the first position and then if it gets called again does it blow up?

You can use the [Call Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx), [Locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx), and [Immediate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) windows to help with your debugging.

Comment: Upsss! I do not know what's I've done, but now it does not.... really strange!

Comment: @MattStannett As you said, there should be anything (i do not know) that was triggering the event, but for any reason, now it does not.

Comment: I would suggest putting your project into version control - sign up for a free account on GitHub or BitBucket and commit chunks that can function independently regularly. That way if the problem comes up again you will be able to see what local changes you have and isolate the problem easier. Also do a clean and rebuild then see if the problem comes back.